# Struggling to install mink and behat using composer for use with symfony2

Tags: symfony, composer-php, behat, mink

I'm trying to install behat and mink with symfony 2.4 using composer but I can't seem to get my composer.json file to an resolve to an installable set of packages.

I installed symfony2 using the command on  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition /path/to/webroot/Symfony 2.4.*
```

Below is my require section of my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "behat/behat":  "2.4.*@stable",
    "behat/mink":   "1.4.*@stable",
    "behat/symfony2-extension":      "*",
    "behat/mink-extension":          "*",
    "behat/mink-browserkit-driver":  "*",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver":   "*"
}
```

I get the following message on the screen after running composer update:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- behat/mink v1.4.0 requires symfony/css-selector >=2.0.0,<2.2.0-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9], symfony/css-selector[2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9].
- behat/mink v1.4.1 requires symfony/css-selector >=2.0,<2.3-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9], symfony/css-selector[2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9].
- behat/mink v1.4.2 requires symfony/css-selector >=2.0,<2.3-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9], symfony/css-selector[2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9].
- behat/mink v1.4.3 requires symfony/css-selector >=2.0,<2.4-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8], symfony/css-selector[2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.3.0].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.3.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.3.2].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.3.3].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.3.4].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.3.5].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.3.6].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.3.7].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.3.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.2.0].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.2.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.2.10].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.2.11].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.2.2].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.2.3].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.2.4].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.2.5].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.2.6].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.2.7].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.2.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.2.9].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.0].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.10].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.11].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.12].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.13].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.2].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.3].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.4].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.5].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.6].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.7].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.8].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.1.9].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, 2.0.7].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.10].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.11].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.12].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.13].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.14].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.15].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.16].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.17].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.18].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.19].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.20].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.21].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.22].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.23].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.24].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.25].
- Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.4.0, v2.0.9].
- don't install symfony/css-selector 2.0.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector 2.0.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector 2.0.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector 2.0.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.15|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.16|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.17|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.18|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.19|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.20|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.21|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.22|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.23|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.24|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.25|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.0.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- don't install symfony/css-selector v2.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.0
- Installation request for symfony/symfony ~2.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.4.0].
- Installation request for behat/mink 1.4.*@stable -> satisfiable by behat/mink[v1.4.0, v1.4.1, v1.4.2, v1.4.3].
```

I just looking to get these to get these componants installed so I can mess around with BDD

Thanks for any help with this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `"behat/mink": "dev-master"` or `"behat/mink": "1.5"` which is compliant with the lastest version of symfony/css-selector.

Comment: Thanks, still required a couple of tweeks but this reply set me on my way. Did you know the answer from experience or was it obvious from the output I pasted into my question? I'm still not sure how I would have resolved it on my own. Thanks

Comment: It was both, but just with the output we can see that behat/mink 1.4.* require a version of symfony (css-selector is a component of symfony) under 2.4-dev so it suggest to remove symfony 2.4. Then if we take a look to the require dependencies of behat/mink in https://packagist.org/packages/behat/mink we can see that indeed it need a version of symfony greater or equal than 2.0 and less than 2.4-dev. So i suggested you to use behat/mink v1.5.0 because it accept symfony ~2.0 (2.0 to 2.9). Sorry for my english, i hope it's clear.

Comment: From the same starting point as the OP, I had to use `"behat/behat ~2.5.0"` and `"behat/mink 1.5"`: `composer require "behat/behat ~2.5.0" "behat/symfony2-extension:*" "behat/mink 1.5" "behat/mink-extension:*" "behat/mink-goutte-driver:*" "behat/mink-selenium2-driver:*"`

Answer (score 3):

Ah, this is again the problem for Symfony 4.2:

```
  Problem 1
    - behat/mink-extension 2.3.0 requires behat/mink ^1.5 -> satisfiable by behat/mink[v1.5.0, v1.6.0, v1.6.1, v1.7.0, v1.7.1].
    - behat/mink-extension 2.3.1 requires behat/mink ^1.5 -> satisfiable by behat/mink[v1.5.0, v1.6.0, v1.6.1, v1.7.0, v1.7.1].
    - behat/mink v1.7.1 requires symfony/css-selector ~2.1|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - behat/mink v1.7.0 requires symfony/css-selector ~2.1 -> no matching package found.
    - behat/mink v1.6.1 requires symfony/css-selector ~2.0 -> no matching package found.
    - behat/mink v1.6.0 requires symfony/css-selector ~2.0 -> no matching package found.
    - behat/mink v1.5.0 requires symfony/css-selector ~2.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for behat/mink-extension ^2.3 -> satisfiable by behat/mink-extension[2.3.0, 2.3.1].
```

And the solution is the same, one needs to use `behat/mink:dev-master`.

For example:

```
$ composer require --dev behat/behat
$ composer require --dev behat/mink:dev-master
$ composer require --dev behat/mink-extension 
$ composer require --dev behat/mink-goutte-driver
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for symfony 2.4

```
    "behat/behat": "2.5.*@stable",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "1.1.*@dev",
    "behat/mink":   "1.5.*@stable",
    "behat/mink-extension":          "*",
    "behat/mink-browserkit-driver":  "*",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver":   "*",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
    "behat/mink-sahi-driver": "*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
```